# Trouble with scraping javascript-powered 'next' buttons with python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a website to learn python and web scraping.
In particular, I was trying to scrape football data at this page: https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/108/Tournaments/5/Seasons/7468/Stages/16548/PlayerStatistics/Italy-Serie-A-2018-2019

My main problem is how to scrape all the pages of the main data table, not just the first one. I am trying to figure it out using selenium and analysing the requests that my browser is sending when I click the 'next' button, but I am having some trouble. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Why is click not working for you? Click, wait for overlay to disappear, process new data table.

Answer (score 0):

Using your browser's network tab when clicking the "next" button you can examine the actual xhr (AJAX) request that is being sent on to the server with each click.
The request is to this URL:

```
https://www.whoscored.com/StatisticsFeed/1/GetPlayerStatistics?category=summary&subcategory=all&statsAccumulationType=0&isCurrent=true&playerId=&teamIds=&matchId=&stageId=16548&tournamentOptions=5&sortBy=Rating&sortAscending=&age=&ageComparisonType=&appearances=&appearancesComparisonType=&field=Overall&nationality=&positionOptions=&timeOfTheGameEnd=&timeOfTheGameStart=&isMinApp=true&page=2&includeZeroValues=&numberOfPlayersToPick=10
```

Notice the "page" query string parameter - this increments with every request you make. Also, the response to each request is actually very easy to parse JSON so you're pretty much good to go.

Comment: Thanks Evyatar, already before I had found the xhr and noticed the page parameter fact, but I just wasn't able to parse it with python. In fact I am not able to retrieve the actual JSON content, just the page containing it .

Comment: I tried setting up the selenium webdriver and called it driver. After getting the page and scraping the first page of the table, I tried playing around with: driver.get(link) but not sure about it.